# Selection Sort for struct

Tags: c++, c, sorting, struct

i'm having an issue with the logic surrounding using selection sort for a struct array. for example say this is my struct :

```
struct data {
    int month
    int day
    ..
    .. }
```

now what I want to do is sort the months and days. I believe I know how to do this for the months, yet am having a hard time understanding how to implement this for days. here is my code for the months so far:

```
void sortData(struct Data yearData[], int sz)
    int i, j, m;
    int temp;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        m = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < sz; j++)
            if (yearData[j].month < yearData[m].month) {
                m = j;
             }

        if (m != i) {
            temp = yearData[i].month;
            yearData[i].month = yearData[m].month;
            yearData[m].month = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I think i want to check to see if the months are the same then look at days and sort them as well. I just don't know if it would be correct to add another iteration to this sort. Thanks!

Comment: As an FYI: C != C++ and you should generally only tag the language you are writing/compiling (the answers may vary greatly).

Comment: any particular reason why you don't use std::sort ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
if((yearData[j].month < yearData[m].month) || 
   ((yearData[j].month == yearData[m].month) && 
    (yearData[j].day < yearData[m].day))) {
    m = j;
}
...
```

However, I am not sure I understand your swap. You should swap the entire struct, not the its members one by one. Consider this:

```
if (m != i) {
  struct Data tmp = yearData[i];
  yearData[i] = yearData[m];
  yearData[m] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: ahhhh that looks like what I want it to do. The reason i don't swap the entire struct is because there is more members than just the months and days in it.

Comment: this is what the struct looks like in its complete form:

Comment: struct Data{
       int day;
       int month;
       int year;
       float high;
       float low;
       float precipitation;
       char condition;
    };

Comment: I understand but you want to sort the elements according to their month/day. if you only move the dates around, you are actually corrupting the data. I am sure this is not what you want.

Comment: ahhhh, so if you just use yearData[ ] for the swap comparisons that will perform the correct sort for months and days not just months? i don't know why I'm struggling to understand this as much as I am when it seems so simple

Comment: ahhhhh because if i don't swap all the months and days will change but the data that they are related to will be messed up which makes it corrupt data?

Comment: exactly, you got it now!

Answer (score 0):

Make a comparison function, then use its result.  The comparison function should return 0 if the structs are equal, -1 if the left should go first, +1 if the right should go first.

It will look something like:

```
int yearDataCmp(struct Data left, struct Data right) {
    if ( left.month < right.month ) { return -1; }
    if ( left.month > right.month ) { return  1; }
    if ( left.day   < right.day   ) { return -1; }
    if ( left.day   > right.day   ) { return  1; }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe i'm allowed to make another function for this. It has to be in the void sortData(struct Data yearData[], int sz) function..

Comment: Fair enough.  Just embed the logic in your main function.  Make a `cmp` variable that defaults to `0` then use the `if` statements from the `yearDataCmp` function.  Instead of returning a value, simply do `cmp = -1` or `cmp = 1` accordingly.